# React Apollo useQuery hook with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to get `useQuery` hook to work with TypeScript.

Here is my query

```
export const FETCH_LINKS = gql`
  query FetchLinks {
    feed {
      links {
        id
        createdAt
        url
        description
     }
  }
}
`;
```

I generated the types from GraphQL schema with `graphql-codegen`

```
export type Feed = {
  __typename?: 'Feed';
  links: Array<Link>;
  count: Scalars['Int'];
};

export type Link = {
  __typename?: 'Link';
  id: Scalars['ID'];
  createdAt: Scalars['DateTime'];
  description: Scalars['String'];
  url: Scalars['String'];
  postedBy?: Maybe<User>;
  votes: Array<Vote>;
};
```

In my component, I apply the type to `useQuery` hook

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery<Feed>(FETCH_LINKS);
```

The problem is that in the `data` variable I receive an object of the following shape:

```
{
feed: {
  __typename
  links
  count
  }
}
```

So, in order to loop through the array of links and render them on the page, I need to do `data.feed.links.map()` but the `Feed` type does not have a `feed` property on it and therefore, I get an error message `Property 'feed' does not exist on type 'Feed'`
How do I rectify this inconsistency

Comment: The obvious solution is to edit the Feed type generated by ```graphql-codegen``` but it does not feel like a correct  way to go about it

Comment: try `useQuery<{ feed: Feed }>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should utilize the [typescript-operations](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-operations) plugin in addition to the `typescript` plugin. This way you will not only generate TS types for the GraphQL types in your schema, but you will also generate types based on the actual queries you use client-side. These additional types can then be plugged directly into the type variables used by the hooks.

Alternatively, you can also use the [typescript-react-apollo](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo) plugin to generate your hooks for you.

If you don't want to use any additional plugins, you'll need to construct the appropriate types for your query and variables yourself:

```
interface FetchLinksData {
  feed: Feed
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you check [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/#typing-hooks) you will see that you would need to create one more interface to represent data:

```
interface FetchLinksData {
  feed: Feed[];
}
```

In component you could use that like this:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery<FetchLinksData>(FETCH_LINKS);
const feeds = data.feed;
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you're using hooks provided by `react-apollo`, you should probably use the official `apollo` cli tool to generate types as well - https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output.
Apollo codegen generates correct types out of the box without having to worry about adding additional plugins.